# Merge Two Columns of Data into a Single Variable

Tags: excel, vba

I have a spreadsheet with two columns of data, both columns have a header.  I would like to establish a variable for each row of data I can then use to generate new worksheet names and insert into formulas.  My variable would be a one to one ratio with the data, meaning A2-B2, A3-B3, etc.  I have tried the following code:

```
 '''Sub CreateSheet2()

 Dim rngBP As Range
 Dim rngCon As Range
 Dim cellBP As Range
 Dim cellCon As Range

 On Error GoTo Errorhandling

 Set rngBP = Application.InputBox(prompt:="Bid Package Select Cell Range:", Title:="Create Sheets", Default:=Selection.Address, Type:=8)
 Set rngCon = Application.InputBox(prompt:="Contractor Select Cell Range:", Title:="Create Sheets", Default:=Selection.Address, Type:=8)

For Each cellBP In rngBP
    
        If cellBP <> "" And cellCon <> "" Then
            
            Sheets.Add(after:=ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets.Count)).Name = cellBP & "-" & cellCon
    
        End If
    
Next cellBP

Errorhandling:

     MsgBox prompt:="Error Detected" & vbNewLine & "Error" & Err.Number & ": " & Err.Description

End Sub'''
```

However, this code generates a variable with all of the possible combinations (A2-B2, A2-B3, A3-B3, etc.).  Ideally, this code would also skip empty cells and not create a variable for that entire row.  Here is a screenshot of my sample dataset.[Sample Dataset](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qe1r1.jpg).  Thank you for the assistance.

Comment: If you know the `Contractor` column is next to the `BidPackage` column, why do you need the second `Application.InputBox`? If `Bid Package Select Cell Range`,. why are you doing `For Each`? Will you be allowing e.g. a `A2,B3` combination? Please do clarify.

Comment: @VBasic2008 I'm not sure I understand where you are headed by asking if it is known if the Contractor column is next to the BP column, can you clarify?  I assumed I needed the second input range in order to capture the Contractor column.  I also assumed the For Each was needed to cycle through the range variables.  For your last question, no a combination outside of A1B1 or A2B2 would ever be allowed.  The data would strictly be locked to adjacent cells.  Hopefully this helps, please let me know if you need additional details or information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Add Worksheets with Names Created from Two Columns

- I see the double `Application.InputBoxes` as a disaster waiting to happen so I abandoned the idea.
- The code will search for the specified headers in the first row and their columns will define the column ranges (from the 2nd to the last row).
- Copy the code into a **standard module**, e.g. `Module1`.
- Adjust the **four** constants.
- You only run the first procedure which will call the second when needed.
- The third procedure is showing an example of proper error handling. Study it closely.

**The Code**

```
Option Explicit

Sub CreateSheet2()

    'On Error GoTo ErrorHandling
    
    Const wsName As String = "Sheet1"
    Const bTitle As String = "Bid Package"
    Const cTitle As String = "Contractor"
    Const FirstRow As Long = 2
    
    Dim wb As Workbook
    Set wb = ThisWorkbook ' The workbook containing this code.
    
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = wb.Worksheets(wsName)
    
    Dim bCol As Variant
    bCol = Application.Match(bTitle, ws.Rows(1), 0)
    
    Dim cCol As Variant
    cCol = Application.Match(cTitle, ws.Rows(1), 0)
    
    Dim LastRow As Long
    LastRow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, bCol).End(xlUp).Row
    
    Dim ColumnOffset As Long
    ColumnOffset = cCol - bCol
    
    Dim SheetNames As Variant
    SheetNames = getSheetNames(wb)
    
    Dim rng As Range
    Set rng = ws.Cells(FirstRow, bCol).Resize(LastRow - FirstRow + 1)
    
    Dim cel As Range
    Dim SheetName As String
    
    For Each cel In rng.Cells
        If cel.Value <> "" And cel.Offset(, ColumnOffset).Value <> "" Then
            SheetName = cel.Value & "-" & cel.Offset(, ColumnOffset).Value
            If IsError(Application.Match(SheetName, SheetNames, 0)) Then
                On Error Resume Next
                wb.Worksheets.Add(After:=wb.Sheets(wb.Sheets.Count)).Name _
                  = SheetName
                If Err Then ' might happen if there are duplicates in columns.
                    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
                    ActiveSheet.Delete
                    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
                End If
                On Error GoTo ErrorHandling
            End If
        End If
    Next cel
    
ProcExit:
    Exit Sub

ErrorHandling:
    MsgBox Prompt:="Error Detected" & vbNewLine & "Error '" & Err.Number _
                 & "': " & Err.Description, _
           Buttons:=vbCritical, _
           Title:="Fail"
    Resume ProcExit

End Sub

Function getSheetNames(Book As Workbook) _
  As Variant
    
    If Book Is Nothing Then
        GoTo ProcExit
    End If
    
    Dim Data As Variant
    ReDim Data(1 To Book.Sheets.Count)
    
    Dim sh As Object
    Dim n As Long
    
    For Each sh In Book.Sheets
        n = n + 1
        Data(n) = sh.Name
    Next sh
    
    getSheetNames = Data

ProcExit:

End Function
```

**Proper Error Handling**

```
Sub ProperErrorHandling()

    On Error GoTo ErrorHandling
    
    
    ' The code
    

ProcExit:
    Exit Sub ' You don't want to show the message if no error and
             ' you must not 'Resume' with no error!

ErrorHandling:
    MsgBox Prompt:="Error Detected" & vbNewLine & "Error '" & Err.Number _
                 & "': " & Err.Description, _
           Buttons:=vbCritical, _
           Title:="Fail"
    ' Sets the error number to 0, but still keeps the error handler active.
    ' Therefore be aware that if you put code between 'ProcExit' and 'Exit Sub'
    ' and an error occurs, it will result in an endless loop.
    Resume ProcExit ' 'Resume', not 'GoTo'!

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you for the potential solution.  I tested this and received an error at line: "If IsError (Match(SheetName, SheetNames, 0)) Then".  The error states "Compile Error: Sub or Function not defined."  I did a Google search and found the Match function typically requires the following syntax: application.worksheetfunction.match(lookup_value,lookup_array,match_type) Does this look accurate to what you were intending?

Comment: @E.Meier: I've edited my code. I found some more mistakes. Sorry. Note that there is a difference between `Application.Match` and `WorksheetFunction.Match`: in AM you can test if error with `IsError`, but with WM you have to use error-handling, e.g. `On Error Resume Next`. Therefore I prefer AM.

Comment: Thank you for the information, I think I understand.  And no problem about the errors, I am entirely self taught with VBA coding and don't fully understand what is correct versus incorrect. I should be able to test out this code tomorrow. I will respond with any questions or comments tomorrow

Comment: Thank you for making the updates, your code works.  I will look through the details and figure out how to use the variables in order to input into formulas on the newly created spreadsheets.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this code.

```
Sub CreateSheet2()

    Const BidPack       As String = "A"         ' specify a column
    Const Contractor    As String = "B"         ' change to suit (to the right of BidPack)
    Const FirstDataRow  As Long = 2             ' change to suit
    
    Dim Wb              As Workbook
    Dim Ws              As Worksheet
    Dim BidRng          As Range
    Dim ConRng          As Range
    Dim Tmp             As Variant              ' misc use
    Dim WsName          As String
    Dim R               As Long                 ' loop counter: rows
    
    Set Wb = ActiveWorkbook                     ' change to suit
    WsName = "Sheet1"                           ' change to suit
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Tmp = Columns(Contractor).Column
    With Wb.Worksheets(WsName)
        Set ConRng = .Range(.Cells(FirstDataRow, Tmp), _
                            .Cells(.Rows.Count, Tmp).End(xlUp))
        ' ConRng and BidRng are of identical size,
        ' not exceeding the number of rows available in ConRng.
        Set BidRng = ConRng.Offset(, Columns(BidPack).Column - Tmp)
        
        For R = 1 To BidRng.Cells.Count
            If (Not IsEmpty(BidRng.Cells(R))) And (Not IsEmpty(ConRng.Cells(R))) Then
                WsName = Format(BidRng.Cells(R).Value, "00-") & ConRng.Cells(R).Value
                On Error Resume Next
                Set Tmp = Wb.Sheets(WsName)
                If Err Then
                    Wb.Sheets.Add(After:=Wb.Sheets(Wb.Sheets.Count)).Name = WsName
                Else
                    MsgBox "A worksheet by the name of """ & WsName & _
                           """ already exists.", vbInformation, _
                           "Duplicate instruction"
                End If
            End If
        Next R
    End With
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you for the potential solution. This works!  I have a clarification question.  Am I correct that the variables "BidRng.Cells(R)" and "ConRng.Cells(R)" can additionally be used as references in formulas?  Thanks again, have a great day.

Comment: `BidRng.Cells(R)` refers to the R*th* cell in the range `BidRng`. That range is declared `Private`, meaning it's accessible only within the procedure where it is defined. Within this scope you can use it in its entirety for other purposes.

Comment: Great! Thank you for the clarification.  So as long as I use those variables associated with the page before the "Next R" command my variable values will remain the same.  Thanks again.  Have a good day.

Comment: Please don't forget to mark the answer that solved your problem as *Selected*. It doesn't need to be this one but it would be nice to show that your problem was, in fact, solved, and how. Thank you.

Comment: This code works, but the variable handling of the other code is easier to use for the subsequent formulas I need to add onto the worksheets.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's best

- loop through `rngBP` range not empty values, only
- using a `Dictionary` object to ensure you're not duplicating sheet names

  ```
   Option Explicit


   Sub CreateSheets()

   Dim rngBP As Range
   Dim cellBP As Range

   On Error GoTo Errorhandling

   Set rngBP = Application.InputBox(prompt:="Bid Package Select Cell Range:", Title:="Create Sheets", Default:=Selection.Address, Type:=8)


   Dim shNamesDict As Object
   Set shNamesDict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

   With ActiveWorkbook
       Dim shName As String
       For Each cellBP In rngBP.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants)

           If Not IsEmpty(cellBP.Offset(, 1).Value2) Then
               shName = cellBP.Value2 & "-" & cellBP.Offset(, 1).Value2
               If Not shNamesDict.exists(shName) Then
                   shNamesDict.Add shName, 0
                   .Sheets.Add(after:=.Worksheets(.Worksheets.Count)).Name = shName
               End If
           End If
       Next
   End With


   Errorhandling:

   If Err.Number <> 0 Then MsgBox prompt:="Error Detected" & vbNewLine & "Error" & Err.Number & ": " & Err.Description

   End Sub
  ```

Comment: Thank you for the potential solution.  I will test this and get back to you with any questions or clarifications.